# How to change the position of an SVG's children with CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm creating the menu icon, and with hover, I want the rects I added inside the SVG to change position, but it doesn't work when I set the y: 45; in the CSS of the SVG.

Here is my code:

```
<button onClick={handleCloseMenu} className='dp-close-aside-menu' aria-controls='primary-navigation' aria-expanded='false'>
        <svg className='svg-menu-arrow' viewBox='0 0 100 100' width='250'>
          <rect className='line top' width={80} height={10}
          x={10} y={15} rx={5}
          ></rect>
          <rect className='line middle' width={80} height={10}
          x={10} y={45} rx={5}
          ></rect>
          <rect className='line bottom' width={80} height={10}
          x={10} y={75} rx={5}
          ></rect>
        </svg>
      </button>
```

And css:

```
.dp-close-aside-menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: end;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    
}
.svg-menu-arrow {
    width: 20px;
    fill: var(--blancod6);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.svg-menu-arrow .line {
    transition: 1s;
    transform-origin: center;
}
.svg-menu-arrow:hover :is(.top, .bottom) {
    y: 45;
}
```

I did this because I needed it urgently, but it's not what I want.

```
.svg-menu-arrow.hover .middle {
    width: 10%;
    transform: translateX(2px);
}
.svg-menu-arrow.hover .top {
    transform: translateY(41.5px);
    rotate: -45deg;
    width: 50%;
}
.svg-menu-arrow.hover .bottom {
    transform: translateY(-41.5px);
    rotate: 45deg;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I know how to do it with transform: translate(), but that's not what I'm looking for. When I hover, I want .top and .bottom to go to the position y: 45.

Comment: Styling `x` and `y` via css is currently not well supported - works in chrome but not in firefox. Using translates is currently your best option for cross-browser comparability